# AJAX Put request from Add-on SDK

Tags: jquery, firefox, request, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

For the last 3 hours, I've been working on making a put request on a Firefox add-on from the *main.js*/*index.js* page with no luck.

From documentation, this is the correct AJAX to call (with the correct site, if you wanted to try to edit it)

```js
$.ajax({
    url:"https://api.myjson.com/bins/1ihp9",
    type:"PUT",
    data:'{"key_updated":"value_updated"}',
    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){

    }
});
```

Firefox Add-on's SDK doesn't use `$.ajax()`, but instead uses `Request()`. So, I've made the code as so:

```js
var latestTweetRequest = Request({
    url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/1ihp9",
    //updatedjson is a string here, as requested in documentation
    content: updatedjson,
    headers: {
        "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "dataType": "json"
    },
    onComplete: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
latestTweetRequest.put();
```

But whatever I do, it just does not work. The response comes out with "constructor{})

I can do a get request to the site just fine.

Comment: Have you checked out the request in network tab? Are there any error codes returned? Is the call even going out? Have you tried a standard get to see if you can even receive data?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly the request object doesn't let you handle errors so when things go wrong you're just left wondering.  You could try using the `net/xhr` module if you want more control.

I'm not sure what the issue is here but it seems like the server doesn't like the object it is seeing.

I found this error message was returned (as a JSON object):

```
{
status:500
message:"Internal Server Error"
more_info:"undefined method `string' for #<PhusionPassenger::Utils::TeeInput:0x007fcf73b9bd98>"
}
```

More importantly here's a quick hack to help you debug things yourself.

```
var { setTimeout } = require("sdk/timers");
setTimeout(function() {
  var latestTweetRequest = Request({
          url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/1ihp9",
          content: updatedjson,    //updatedjson is a string here, as requested in documentation
          headers: {
              "contentType" : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              "dataType" : "json"
          },
          onComplete: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
          },
          onError: function (err) {
            console.error(err);
          }
      });
      latestTweetRequest.put();

}, 1000 * 20);
```

This code gives wraps your request in a 20 second delay timer.  That is 20 seconds from the time Firefox starts up and runs this add-on code, so not a lot of time but just enough to complete this task.

Once Firefox has started up via your `jpm run` command.  Immediately go to the Tools menu.  Open Tools -> Web Developer -> Browser Toolbox.  The window opened will look like the Firefox DevTools but you're actually debugging the whole browser.  Now quickly go to the network tab and if you did all this before 20 seconds expired you'll see your network request go through and be able to inspect it.

Good luck!